# Before plugin doesnt work

Tags: magento2, plugin, before-plugin

I'm trying to add a dash (-) in-store code in magento2. Magento by default doesn't allow it. Below is the function which does the validation.

```
protected function _getValidationRulesBeforeSave()
{
    $validator = new \Magento\Framework\Validator\DataObject();

    $storeLabelRule = new \Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
    $storeLabelRule->setMessage(__('Name is required'), \Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY);
    $validator->addRule($storeLabelRule, 'name');

    $storeCodeRule = new \Zend_Validate_Regex('/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9_]*$/i');
    $storeCodeRule->setMessage(
        __(
            'The store code may contain only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore (_),'
            . ' and the first character must be a letter.'
        ),
        \Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH
    );
    $validator->addRule($storeCodeRule, 'code');
    return $validator;
}
```

Now I wanted to add a plugin to the `$validator->addRule` method to modify the validation. Here is how I'm doing it.

In `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Validator\DataObject">
        <plugin name="custom-storecode-rule" type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Validator\DataObject" disabled="false" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now created the class here `app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Plugin/Validator/DataObject.php`

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Validator;

class DataObject
{
    public function beforeAddRule(
        \Magento\Framework\Validator\DataObject $subject,
        \Zend_Validate_Interface $validator, 
        $fieldName = ''
    ) {
        if ($fieldName == 'code') {
            $storeCodeRule = new \Zend_Validate_Regex('/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9_\-]*$/i');
            $storeCodeRule->setMessage(
                __(
                    'The store code may contain only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore (_) or dash (-)'
                    . ' and the first character must be a letter.'
                ),
                \Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH
            );
        }

        return [$storeCodeRule, $fieldName];
    }
}
```

But it doesn't trigger.

Comment: Have you tried to log some message from the plugin?

Comment: Yeah.. removed those messages for posting it here. I had 2-3 messages there. 1 in this _getValidationRulesBeforeSave method. Another one inside $validator->addRule and 1 inside the plugin. All prints except the plugin's one.

Comment: I am not sure but I think plugins don't work for the classes under Magento Framework.

Comment: Based on Magento's devdocs, Plugins can not be used on Objects that are instantiated before Magento\Framework\Interception is bootstrapped.

Comment: Its not a class from Magento\Framework\Interception.

Comment: My guess would be that the class is not instanciated via the object manager or not injected trough the constructor so it just load the class like it is without any plugins on it.

Comment: @CarloRicci you are correct. $validator is created using the new keyword thus it's impossible to create a plugin on it. The preference system would not wotk either because of the same reason.  OP: Meaning you need to find another place in the code to do this or use a composer patch. I would suggest look at why you think a hyphen is required in your store codes if core doesn't allow it. It's rarely a good idea to rewrite these rules in the framework especially if there is no technical need to do so.